# Convert Array into Object and paste values into a different column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column that contains a text like this on each row (text is different) - `ABC1 London - ACompany: Ground Floor, Main Tower, 127 Bridge Street, London AB1 1JZ`.

The script I have extracted the city name from that text and store it into a new array.

When I try to write those values into a new column I get `Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 18, file "Code")`.

I have tried to loop through that array again, but it returns 101 arrays (I have 101 rows) so when I set cities[0].length as width it pastes it on 101 column.

All I need is to get the city name from the text and paste it on the same sheet to a different column - Ex. the text is on column B12 and I want to paste just the city name into R12 - hope it makes sense.

Please see below the code I have

```
function getCity() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Response Data');
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var cities = [];
  var newCity = []
  for (var i=1;i<values.length;i++)
  {

    var cellText = values[i][11];
    if(typeof cellText === 'number') {continue;};
    cities.push(cellText.substring(5, (cellText + " -").indexOf("-") - 1));
  }

  Logger.log(cities);

  sh.getRange(2, 18, cities.length, 1).setValues(cities);


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any errors that you are getting?

Comment: Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 18, file "Code")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and see if you're getting the same error,

```
function getCity() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Response Data');
  var range = sh.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var cities = [];
  var newCity = []
  for (var i=1;i<values.length;i++)
  {
    var cellText = values[i][11];
    if(typeof cellText === 'number') {continue;};
    cities.push([cellText.substring(5, (cellText + " -").indexOf("-") - 1)]);
  }
  Logger.log(cities);
  sh.getRange(2,18,cities.length,1).setValues(cities);
}
```

Comment: I get `Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 101 (line 15, file "Code")`

Comment: Share sample spreadsheet with sample data, there is something wrong `.getRange(2, 18, cities.length, 1)` with this part

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoHkogaCMpozdRsVdErMNbQTaTgZaG5DORO_4kGHKl8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It does! :) Thank you very much .... need to push more and learn arrays :)

Comment: All the best :)